# How to use Stretch/testing packages?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, apt, source.list

I want to install the last version of Deluge on my Raspbian.

The current distribution, Jessie (stable), contains the 1.3.10 version but I want the last one 1.3.13.

The next distribution, Stretch (testing), contains the 1.3.13 version.

How can I enable apt to get the packages from the Stretch distribution?

Comment: Also you can try with Dietpi, they have a Stretch alpha image: http://dietpi.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=986

Answer (score 16):

I've adapted the instructions [here](https://serverfault.com/a/382101) to our case.

First, create the following files in `/etc/apt/preferences.d`:

**`jessie.pref`**:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=jessie
Pin-Priority: 900
```

**`stretch.pref`**:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=stretch
Pin-Priority: 750
```

Now, creating a matching set for /etc/apt/sources.list.d:

**`jessie.list`**:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

**`stretch.list`**:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

Finally update the packages list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And now you can install Deluge from the Stretch distribution:

```
sudo apt-get install deluged -t stretch
```

Obtaining:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ deluged --version
deluged: 1.3.13
libtorrent: 0.16.18.0
```

Comment: As per @prisma 's answer, I had to change a=jessie to n=jessie for it to work correctly.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for a single package on Raspbian? I just need a dev version of network-manager.

Answer (score 0):

Except for this does not work for raspbian:

```
Pin: release a=jessie
```

Does not correctly match jessie

```
cat  /var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_stretch_InRelease

...
Origin: Raspbian
Label: Raspbian
Suite: testing
Codename: stretch
...
```

there is no Archive tag in the releasefile of raspbian, so one needs to match n= (Codename)

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=jessie
Pin-Priority: 900
```

...works for me.