# Upgrading systemd version on raspberry pi 3

Tags: systemd

I am trying to update my pi3's systemd version from 215 to the newest build. Does anyone know is this is possible or not? Thank you.

Comment: There's no good path forward because Raspbian is based on Debian stable, which is shipping an outdated systemd version. If Raspbian were based on the latest stable Ubuntu LTS release instead, a number of software packages like systemd would be newer (229 vs 215), but the overall system feel would be the same, since Ubuntu is based on Debian.

Comment: @MarkStosberg Good Point!  In that case, maybe one of the [Ubuntu images for the Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) would be the best way to get a newer `systemd`.

Comment: @Hydraxan14 I would consider that. I don't know if there are special additions that only exist on Raspian. I haven't looked into it. I already use Ubuntu on my desktop and servers, so I would heavily consider trying it for my next Pi project. (My last one powers of a kiosk display of a solar panel systems stats).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newest build should be included in one of the repositories. Let's suppose that you are using a raspbian system. First you need to update before getting the upgrade.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If you only want to upgrade your systemd version to the compiled newer one available just select it:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade systemd
```

Comment: @Zotto For systemd, it should be `sudo apt-get upgrade systemd`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad head and writing fast . Thank you for your correction

Comment: dang, it did not upgrade the version of systemd, still 215

Comment: That is because no higher version of systemd is available in the repositories, compiled for ARM. You can wait until a stable and tested version is ready, or you can try to compile yourself ones, but is a little risky if you are not too experienced

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, It Is Possible

While the current version of `systemd` in Raspbian Stable (Jessie) is `215-17+deb8u7`, there are ways to get newer versions.

---

### Testing Repository (Stretch), Unstable Repository (Sid)

A later version might be available in either the repository for Raspbian Testing (Stretch) or Raspbian Unstable (Sid).  Be aware that the newer software is more likely to be less stable:

```
Older (More Stable) <----------------> Newer (Less Stable)

Jessie (Stable) .... Stretch (Testing) .... Sid (Unstable)
```

You'll have to enable these repository manually.  [This stackexchange answer looks promising](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/59436/46007).

---

### Third Party Repository

If the testing version is still too old, there's a chance that some third party offers a newer, compiled and packaged version of `systemd` for Raspbian Jessie.  You'll have to search the Internet for this.

Be cautious:  Like any other software you download from random places on the Internet, there's a chance to get malware on your Pi this way, though I have not heard of such incidents.

---

### Compile From Source

Failing the above, you can compile `systemd` from the source code yourself, which is probably quite an involved process.

Good luck!

Comment: I am not the most experienced person with the raspberry pi, for the testing repo (Sid), what is that stackexchange post talking about exactly? what is he upgrading?

Comment: 'Sid' is [unstable, **not** testing](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianUnstable#Life_cycle); testing is currently 'stretch'.   I'm not sure that Raspbian actually keeps the former, but in any case, if you are new to the OS I strongly recommend you *do not use sid or stretch for systemd.*

Comment: @goldilocks You are totally right.  I don't usually stray from stable so I didn't recall all the details correctly.  I've updated my answer now.

Comment: These are all technically valid options, but are asking for trouble. They *might* work, but the rest of the packages on Jessie have been tested with systemd 215. If run an unsupported systemd version, you could be trying package combinations that have been lightly tested or never tested together, and people will be less able and willing to offer you help since you would be running an unsupported combination of packages-- if it even works for you.